# Datatables render adding random characters in header (== $0)

Tags: datatables

In the fifth column of my table which is populated from ajax, outside of the  code is ==$0 which is not part of the html.
Screenshot from Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iohkl.png

This breaks the whole table... I have no idea where this code is coming from.

Using datatables 1.10.12.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this appears to be a Chrome debugging value? I suppose it is not part of the actual document. There must be another issue in my table.